# Error message on validation control appearing in wrong spot

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

I have the following block of code

```
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ValidationExpression=".{3,50}"
    CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field needs to be 3 to 50 characters." />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
    CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
```

And the error message for the `RequiredFieldValidator` appears after the error message for the `RegularExpressionValidator`  Look below at the screenshots to see what I'm talking about.  I'd like "The user name field is required" to appear where "The user name field needs to be 3 to 50 characters" is.

[image: Range error]
[image: required error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using CSS.

You Just Add **style="margin-left:-300px;"** in your "RequiredFieldValidator" Like

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" style="margin-left:-300px;"
    CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
```

**Note:**

1)Adjust "-300px" to your required length.

2)This style can also give in css class or id also.

3)Not only by using margin-left,but also we can achieve this by using different techniques in CSS.

More about CSS:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/

http://html.net/tutorials/css/

Comment: I downvoted because this one of the worst possible and error prone solutions. Lets imagine that author of the question has more than one page with the same issue. There could be situations where `300px` is not enough or too much. The author will end up with a bunch of inline styles with different inline margins and when page layout will change author will be forced to check all pages and recalculate the offsets.
And inline styles are also counter productive to use when it comes to fixing issues with styling.

Comment: Thank you Alexander manekovskiy.I clearly mentioned that adjust size(-300px) based on required length.i dont mean that take -300px exactly .i just give example(Not exact solution).I simply said that it is possible by using css.Thats why i mentioned hyperlinks for learning html and css.There a lot solutions in html for the above problem rather than using typical code in asp.net.Please revise the solution once.till you unsatisfied.please give necessary advice to me to modify the solution.I hope you understood now.Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET validation controls have property [`Display`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.display%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which defines how error message is shown and how it is "hidden" input is valid. In your situation you should use `Dynamic` value for display as it sets `display: none` to the valid validators causing them not to occupy the real estate of the page.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="UserName" ValidationExpression=".{3,50}"
    CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field needs to be 3 to 50 characters." />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="UserName"
    CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
```

Also make sure that your css class `field-validation-error` is not overriding the `display` or `visibility` css attributes.

Also I would suggest to use `CompareValidator` instead of `RegularExpressionValidator` to control the length of the user input.